# Не хотели бы вы выдвинуть свою кандидатуру на этих выборах?

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы

Ссылка

> Не хотели бы вы выдвинуть свою кандидатуру на этих выборах?

показывается даже если кандидатура уже выдвинута. Ведёт на правку предвыборной речи, так что ссылка нормальная, но её надо бы переформурлировать.

Comment: Поздно уже выдвигаться :) Теперь до следующих выборов.

Comment: @AK, у кого-то есть год на исправления косяка. О1 Я завтра ещё один запощу, как до скриншота доберусь :)

Comment: @Qwertiy а то и два. С теми темпами, как тут всё идет.

Comment: А то и два. [Пример тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6139/213987).

Answer (score 3):

Оригинальная строка [выглядит](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264136?key=ca6b516ced80b3d8c15ea977f1e49fec) так:

> Would you like to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election?

То есть перевод вполне соответствует оригиналу.

Мы конечно можем исправить его, чтобы он стал описывать действие в общем случае (до и после выдвижения), но я не считаю такой подход правильным.

Лучше, чтобы в движке появилось разделение и две отдельные строки, которые можно правильно перевести. Таким образом, в данном случае это не проблема локализации как таковая.