# Нет перевода для We will calculate the winners

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Абзац [по-прежнему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2055/213987) не переведён:

> We will calculate the winners using OpenSTV with the Meek STV method,
>   which automatically weights users' votes in the way that does the most
>   good for the candidates they have selected, in order of preference.

[image: не переведен абзац]

Comment: Перевод не желаете предложить? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мы определим победителей при помощи сервиса [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/) по методике [Meek STV](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1999/), используя взвешенные голоса участников для того, чтобы выбрать наиболее хороших кандидатов в порядке ваших предпочтений.

Comment: [Заменил линк](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40612881#40612881) на русскоязычное описание метода.

Comment: Этот вариант теперь используется в переводе.

Answer (score 0):

> Мы определим победителей по алгоритму `[Meek STV](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1999/)` с помощью сервиса OpaVote.

Думаю, что можно не объяснять алгоритм ещё раз. Краткая суть есть на абзац выше (про приоритеты), подробное объяснение есть по [ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1999/).